# Bootstrap tooltip not displayed on the first mouse hover action on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a basic back to top Bootstrap button that works perfectly except that its (Bootstrap) tooltip only shows up on the second mouse hovering action, any idea this is not working on the first mouse hovering?

Html side:

```
<body>
[...]
<a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg back-to-top" role="button" title="Click to return on the top page" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>
[...]
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript side:

```
<script>
    function fadeInBody() {
        $('body').fadeIn(500);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        fadeInBody();

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 5) {
                $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $('#back-to-top').click(function () {
            $('#back-to-top').tooltip('hide');
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });

        $('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: May be try using 'data-title' instead of 'data-toggle'.

Comment: I tried your code on jsFiddle, it works. My hypothesis is that you are missing some import or your scripts are loaded later. Please post your entier page to verify ;)

Comment: @MohamedBathaoui thanks sounds like most likely loading order issue, I am gonna check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the issue on my side.

I think the underlying problem is related to your jQuery ready event handler, you actually don't need to call `$('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');`:

```
<script>
    function fadeInBody() {
        $('body').fadeIn(500);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        fadeInBody();

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 5) {
                $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $('#back-to-top').click(function () {
            $('#back-to-top').tooltip('hide');
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);
            return false;
        });

        // Try to comment this out below
        // $('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only shared the child element it makes it harder to debug, but I usually put the `data-tooltip` on the parent element containing the `<a>` tag. I also never used the `data-trigger` parameter, but it doesn't seem to be creating the glitch you're talking about.

Is your script loaded at the end of your `<body>` tag?

Hope this helps!

Comment: well the data-trigger was more a desperate attempt with or without the behaviour is the same. I am going to investigate a bit more the loading order.